# In studying waveguide mode vectors I have difficulty in interpreting the expression

Tags: curl

The components of $E$ waves are,
\begin{equation}
e_x=k_x k_z C_E^{\mathrm{rect}} \mathrm{cos}\left(k_x x\right)\mathrm{sin}\left(k_y y\right) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_y=k_y k_z C_E^{\mathrm{rect}} \mathrm{sin}\left(k_x x\right)\mathrm{cos}\left(k_y y\right)
\end{equation}

what it the physical meaning of $\hat{z} \cdot \mathrm{rot}_t e=0$ and when $\hat{z} \cdot \mathrm{rot}_t e\neq0$

My first guess was that there is no rotating field of $e$ exist in the direction of $z$?